# Close WebSocket Threadsafe

Tags: multithreading, websocket, asp.net-core

Using `System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket` I have a read loop in one thread.

```
var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
```

From another thread I Write.

```
lock (ws)
    ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

This works fine.

My question is, how can I cleanly close this connection?

Any attempts to close result in an exception:

```
await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Bye", CancellationToken.None);
InvalidOperationException: 'Concurrent reads are not supported.'
```

I've tried to pass a `CancellationToken` to `ws.ReceiveAsync` so that I could call `ws.CloseAsync` from inside the receive loop. That didn't interrupt the `ReceiveAsync` call, it returned when the next message arrived.

Is it possible to cleanly close the socket outside the read loop.
I could implement a "Close connection" message but that seems overkill when there is a concept of sending a close message in the WebSocket protocol.

Comment: Are you *sure* the `CancellationToken` won't cancel the `ReceiveAsync`? That seems very odd.

Comment: @StephenCleary at at least not before the next message arrives 5-10 seconds later

Comment: In that case, you'll need to call `CloseOutputAsync` and handle the `CloseSent` message type in your reads.

Comment: @StephenCleary `CloseOutputSync` worked. I don't know where to get the `CloseSent` message, at the next return of `ReveiveAsync` the socket appeared to be completely closed which is all I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In that case, you'll need to call CloseOutputAsync and handle the
>   CloseSent message type in your reads. – Stephen Cleary Mar 14 at 13:49

You can call `CloseOutputAsync` while another thread is waiting on `ReceiveAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a concurrent read in this code - if you are calling `ReceiveAsync` only from a single thread and if you await the result of the operation before starting the next one there should not be this exception. Where is it thrown?

Suggestion for the writing part: If you use a lock and a blocking write (with `.Wait()`) you are blocking a full thread (which potentially runs other handles), which might not be what you want. Better use `SemaphoreSlim` instead, where you can do:

```
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
    await ws.SendAsync();
}
finally
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

If the text of the error message is not precise and it actually complains about a concurrent `Send` and `Close` then you could use the same semaphore also for protecting the `Close` call:

```
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
    await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Bye", CancellationToken.None);
}
finally
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: The exception is thrown at the `CloseAsync` call.